# Are Maybe String and Maybe Int both Monoids in Haskell?

Tags: string, haskell, integer, option-type, monoids

I´ve gotten into a bit of confusion whether Maybe Int and Maybe String are both monoids in Haskell because i dont really know what functions you can apply to Int or String in terms of monoids with their neutral element and associativity rules! Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 6):

There is a `Monoid` instance for any `Maybe a` as long as `a` itself has a `Monoid` instance; the combination of two `Just` values simply combines the wrapped values according to their instance, while anything combined with `Nothing` is itself `Nothing`.

`String` has a `Monoid` instance by virtue of being an alias of `[Char]`; all lists are monoids via list concatenation with the empty list as the identity. As a result, `Maybe String` is a monoid as well.

```
> Just "Fo" <> Just "o"
Just "Foo"
> Just "Fo" <> Nothing
Just "Fo"
```

`Maybe Int` is not a monoid, because `Int` is not a monoid. This is because there are multiple choices for how to make `Int` a monoid, so no one choice is chosen as special. Instead, several new types are defined with distinct `Monoid` instances to clarify which operation you want to use.

```
> import Data.Monoid
> (3 :: Int) <> 5

<interactive>:8:1: error:
    • No instance for (Semigroup Int) arising from a use of ‘<>’
    • In the expression: (3 :: Int) <> 5
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = (3 :: Int) <> 5

-- (+) and 0
> Sum (3 :: Int) <> Sum 5
Sum {getSum = 8}

-- (*) and 1
> Product (3 :: Int) <> Product 5
Product {getProduct = 15}

> Just (Sum (3 :: Int)) <> Just (Sum 5)
Just (Sum {getSum = 8})
> Just (Sum (3 :: Int)) <> Nothing
Just (Sum {getSum = 3})
```

Comment: `Sum` and `Product` have `Num` instances, so you don't need to explicitly use their constructors. `3 <> 5 :: Sum Int` also works. (I actually think you made the right pedagogical choice in this answer, because the question seems to be a beginner one and explicitly including constructors may be less confusing for them, but perhaps there will be non-beginners perusing this one day...)

Comment: `Just "Fo" <> Nothing == Just "Fo"`

Comment: @PaulJohnson I always forget which way the `Maybe` monoid is defined.

Answer (score 2):

The `Monoid` instance for `Maybe` types [has been defined as <sup>[src]</sup>](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-444):

> ```
> instance Semigroup a => Monoid (Maybe a) where
>     mempty = Nothing
> ```

it thus requires `Int` or `String` to be instances of the [**`Semigroup`** type class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Semigroup). Since a `String` is the same as `type String = [Char]` and thus a list of `Char`s, this is the case, indeed [we see <sup>[src]</sup>](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-301):

> ```
> instance Semigroup [a] where
>         (<>) = (++)
>         {-# INLINE (<>) #-}
>
>         stimes = stimesList
> ```

so it will append the two lists, and for a `Maybe` [this means <sup>[src]</sup>](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-428):

> ```
> instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (Maybe a) where
>     Nothing <> b       = b
>     a       <> Nothing = a
>     Just a  <> Just b  = Just (a <> b)
>
>     stimes = stimesMaybe
> ```

This thus means that for two `Maybe String`s, the neutral element is `Nothing` and the binary operator will append the two strings wrapped in `Just …` data constructors if these are both `Just`s, the `Just` one if one of the two is a `Just`, or `Nothing` if both items are `Nothing`s.

This is not the case for an `Int`, indeed. For integers there can be multiple `Monoid` instances, for example ⟨ℤ,+, 0⟩ or ⟨ℤ,×, 1⟩.